# spring batch remote partition with multiple tables

Tags: spring-batch

I have developed one app where we have to process more than 5 million records from one large table. We have used spring batch remote partitioning a  it is working fine.

I now have to use same job and tweak it to create partition for multiple table. Each partition will have table name and min and max records so slave knows from which table it has to read data and prepare file.

my question is, is this something can be done if yes then is there any sample out there on github.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done.  You'll need to implement your own `Partitioner` to handle the logic of creating `ExecutionContexts` for each table/row range.

A couple good resources:

- `Partitioner` interface documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html
- Section 7.4 of Spring Batch's Scaling and Parallel Processing chapter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html
- My introduction to Spring Batch video covers partitioning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU and the related Github repository: https://github.com/mminella/Spring-Batch-Talk-2.0

Comment: Thank you Michael. I did watch you video on spring developer channel and because of that my first implementation went really well. So thank you very much for spring batch deep dive.

Comment: After trying custom partitioner which was able to partition my two table with proper partition info, i am facing a problem on slave side. Where my slave custom reader was reading parition info from step execution but it was keep processing same parition and going in to endless loop. What do I have to return back to tell the aggegator that this partition has been successfully processed ?

Comment: The `ItemReader` must return `null` to indicate that the input has been exhausted.  If the step exits normally, Spring Batch (specifically the `StepExecutionRequestHandler`) will handle the rest.